# Mybatis mapping getTimeInMillis

Tags: sql, mybatis

I would like to say something to the effect of getCurrentTimeInMilliseconds

```
<insert id="insertToMyTable" parameterType="MyStuff">
    insert into my_table ( name, id, amount, modified_time )
    values (
        #{item.bondId}, 
        #{item.clientId}, 
        #{item.amount},
        $$-getCurrentTimeInMilliseconds-$$
     )
</insert>
```

I am currently implementing getCurrentTimeInMilliseconds as a java-method on the MyStuff object and it is an ugly workaround (it's not part of the MyStuff object data and is there purely as a hack-method to record database information)

if it was written in SQL I'd want to be as close to ANSI-SQL as possible - i.e. not running differently on every vendor

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any answer better than using substituing with UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - which works for MySQL. You can do 0+CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() which is Ansi SQL compatible but leaves your result as 20130303434332221 style int, not 13069293487 style (i.e. milisecond count). If that makes sense